# Abaraham's twitteroauth 500 server error

Tags: php, twitter-oauth

I've put the files on my server. I've set up an application with Twitter. I've put the consumer key and consumer secret into the config.php along with the proper URL for the callback. However when I go to the root of the twitteroauth installation I get a 500 Interal Server Error. Is there some step I'm missing on setting this up?

## Update

Ok. Digging a little deeper it appears that this part of the OAuth.php file is what's causing the error.

```
class OAuthException extends Exception {
  // pass
}
```

That sits at the very top of the file. If I comment that out everything seems to load fine. Any ideas why that would cause a 500 Internal Server Error?

Comment: I've tracked down the issue to something happening within the Oauth.php file included in the twitteroauth/ subfolder.

Comment: There is an open issue with the OAuth library to fix this. https://code.google.com/p/oauth/issues/detail?id=157

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a bunch of testing this seems to be the fix. If you have the OAuth module for PHP installed on your server you need to comment out the OAuthException class in the OAuth.php file in the twitteroauth subfolder otherwise there will be a conflict with the module because the module already has an exception handler with the same name, and you'll get this 500 Internal Server Error.